# How to let a UIImage only stretch in a specific area?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

```
var contentImageView: UIImageView!{
    didSet{
        contentImageView.image!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 5,left: 5,bottom: 5,right: 5))
    }
}
```

I have tried this code after searching in the Internet.

But it didn't work and the result is:

[image]

Are there any better ways to implement?

Comment: image is right but your insets make it wrong

Comment: @Bhavin What's wrong with the inset?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a sleek option in Xcode .xcassets. You can select the images and slice it from there so that it's strechable in specific parts only below are the images please explore this option.
[image]
[image]
[image: For your purpose just select the middle option (slice vertically and horizontally) for chat bubble.]

1. For your purpose just select the middle option (slice vertically and horizontally) for chat bubble.

[image: After Slicing.]

2. After Slicing.

[image: Top Image is image with slicing. Bottom image is image without slicing.]

3. Top Image is image with slicing. Bottom image is image without
   slicing.

**Borrowed Bhavin's Image for demonstration :D**

Comment: Thanks!! I did this and the image shows perfectly! This is a good ways ! Thx very much!

Comment: Good to hear. There are many freebies in Xcode yet to be explored. :D

Comment: how to increase image size based on textSize @PrajeetShrestha

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode;
```

`capInsets` is a specific area(e.g. `UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 18, 10, 18)`), `resizingMode` should select `UIImageResizingModeStretch` .

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 18, 10, 18) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
bubbleImageView.image = image;
```

Comment: var image = UIImage(named: "bubble")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10), resizingMode: .Stretch)