# Chat Item view with top corner, border and shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create custom cell that looks like chat item. 
Challenges are: adding triangle to top corner and making common border and shadow of chat item?

Width of all "clouds" is the same.

What is the best way to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: check this  https://github.com/RobinChao/ChatMessageTableViewController

Comment: Thank you, this ViewController creates cell like iMessages, but my cell is little more complicated

Comment: in your tableview display sender and reciever message in left side?

Comment: No, it is way how odd and even cells look like

Comment: I have suggestion you can make 1px with image then you can set on imageview and starch.

Comment: This is use full link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823130/how-to-let-a-uiimage-only-stretch-in-a-specific-area

Comment: width of all "clouds" is the same

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea:

Create subclass **Triangle** of **UIView** to draw "*tail*" of "*cloud*":

```
class LeftTriangleView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        context.closePath()

        context.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}



class RightTriangleView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        context.closePath()


        context.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let leftTailView: LeftTriangleView = {
        let tail = LeftTriangleView()
        tail.backgroundColor = .white
        tail.isHidden = true

        return tail
    }()

let rightTailView: RightTriangleView = {
        let tail = RightTriangleView()
        tail.backgroundColor = .white
        tail.isHidden = true

        return tail
    }()

let cloudView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return view
    }()



addSubview(cloudView)
addSubview(leftTailView)
addSubview(rightTailView)



leftTailView.anchor(topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: bubbleView.leftAnchor, topConstant: 5, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 9, heightConstant: 6)

rightTailView.anchor(topAnchor, left: bubbleView.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 5, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 9, heightConstant: 6)



If send message: 

rightTailView.isHidden = false


If received message: 

leftTailView.isHidden = false
```