# Resize background image based on UITableViewCell Label height and width

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am able to adjust the Custom `UITablleViewCell` label width and height based on the text. It looks like below.

[image]

Now i want to set the below chat bubble image to the label as background so that the bubble adjusts its size based on label text and gives the bubble effect similar to other messengers.

[image]

Below is my code for setting the image as background of label.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChatConversationTableViewCell";

            ChatConversationTableViewCell *cell = (ChatConversationTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatConversationTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            cell.chatmsgLabel.text = [chatHistoryArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.timeAndDateMsgLabel.text = [timeAndDateMsgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble2.png"];
CGSize imgSize = cell.timeAndDateMsgLabel.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

cell.timeAndDateMsgLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];

            return cell;


}
```

The output looks like

[image]

My expected output is

[image]

For more info below is my CustomTableViewCell and its constraints

[image]

[image]

I tried a lot to achieve the output but i am unable to figure out. Are there any other approaches to achieve the output, i am ready to follow any approach which suits my requirement. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: See this link it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823130/how-to-let-a-uiimage-only-stretch-in-a-specific-area

Comment: You can view this project as an reference: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController .May be helpful for you. This Controls is stretching image in well manner.

Comment: you need to set same color background to label instead of image . and give grater than equal constraint to that label .

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can set all the **imageView constraints to zero**. 
Then you can **add the image in the .xassets file** and then use **slicing** the image. This will stretch the image when necessary and shrink it. 
[image]

> Slicing is upto you.

[image: Image of my storyboard]

[image: Output]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Interesting i want to acheive the above ui mentioned by you but I dont have any imageview in my tableviewcell to set constraints. I have set the imageview as background to my label in UITableViewCell. Any suggestion how you have set the imageview?

Comment: See the answer I updated. I gave the image of the storyboard. I took an image view in the cell and the text level on the image view.

Comment: Note that you can create once and for all a "sliced" image (look at the doc of UIImage (the part with "Stretchable"). That should avoid you to recreate all the time the image with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried your approach but no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/rubaiyat6370/iOS/blob/master/MessegingApplication.zip See this project. Hope it will help you a bit. @Madhu

Comment: could u help me with how how will i do that @mumu

Answer (score 0):

You can solve problem by doing below;

1. Create an UIView.
2. Set a background to it.
3. Add your label inside this UIView.

Set all constraints zero to this view.

This can be solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Do below steps:

1. Take a UIView (says, myView) and give its constraints and clear backGround Color.

   - Top bottom trailing to superview.
   - leading to superview with relationship `<=` and medium priority.
   - width constant with relationship `>=` and higher priority then leading.
   - height with relationship `>=`.
2. Now add ImageView in myView with constraints,

   - leading, trailing top, bottom to superview.
3. Add Label for text_mesage, time, seen into the myview and give constraints accordingly.

Now run your project and check. If still there any issue then let me know.